# Geographical extension of „ahí” with stressed „a”

Tags: diferencias-regionales, acentuación

I have heard:

> **a**hí (te) va
>
> **a**hí voy
>
> **a**hí me hablas mañana

which nevertheless is pronounced stressed **a**, forming rather than a hiatus, a diphthong. For sure it's not meant *ay*, the interjection, since demonstrative *ahí* makes sense. I wonder which is the geographical extension of this. I guess it's pretty much the same case as Argentinian/Uruguayan Spanish, where written accents are not always taken into account.

Suppose you want to write a novel, where you want somebody like *hear* saying *ahí* in this intonation. How do you write it?!

Comment: This is quite usual in colloquial speech in Aragón (Spain).

Comment: This never happensn in Chile.

Comment: Never heard that in Bolivia.

Comment: Never heard that in Colombia either.

Comment: It is also commonly used in Madrid. "Ahí me hablas mañana" doesn't sound too natural here but "ahí va" is used a lot (pronounced [aj'βa], or *ay va*): "Es *ahí va*, aunque se pronuncie como indica. Este desplazamiento del acento prosódico se da en otras interjecciones (por ejemplo, *¡anda!* se pronuncia a menudo /andá/). No es, por tanto, *¡ay va!* (como tampoco *¡hay va!*)." ([Fundeu](http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/ahi-va-o-ay-va-14795/)).

Comment: @Yay That's helpful. Suppose you want to write a novel, where you want somebody like *hear* saying *ahí* in this intonation. How do you write it?!

Comment: @c.p. I would still write it as *ahí*. If  readers are familiar with this intonation, they will pronounce it as *ay* however you write it, and if they are not, they won't understand why you spelled it as *ay* and will take it as a typo. In any case, I think it is preferable to go with *ahí*. As an aside, a similar stress shift happens with the adverb *sino*, often pronounced as *sinó* but never written with the accent mark.

Comment: Nice, thank you. That is good stuff, more than enough for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Mexico it's extremely popular:

> **a**hí te encargo a la niña
>   **a**hí nos estamos hablando

But I think you're from there as well...

Answer (score 1):

In many places, spanish speakers are used to pronouncing words in a different way when using a coloquial language. I think this is the case, in Mexico is very common to hear people pronouncing it in that way, but is not correct when talking properly.
The meaning is the same as **ahí**, with no stress.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just a bad pronunciation of the word. Just a colloquialism. In my region, Andalusia, there some people that pronounce wrongly the word "vacía", and say "vacia". I think it the same but more extended. I can say that in the south of Spain we pronounce ah**í**.

Good luck with your research!